# How can I restrict SSH to only listen for requests from my local network?

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, openssh

I am a beginner and new to development boards and Linux as a whole, and have been using the wonderful SSH package with Debian (I believe this is OpenSSH) to tinker around and learn more without the need to be physically connected to my Pi through a serial cable.

I have followed various websites and threads on this forum to harden and tweak my SSH to be more secure. An important change I'd like to make to my `sshd_config` file has vexed me however - `ListenAddress`. As I understand it, the `ListenAddress` value in `sshd_config` defines the strict parameter of IP address(es) the server should listen to requests from.

The default value for `ListenAddress` in `sshd_config` is `0.0.0.0`, which is commented out. I understand that working on a **"commented out defaults"** policy, the application will default to this value. I've read the [Man[ual] Page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html) which indicates the default is to

> listen on all local addresses on the current routing domain

and while I can't profess to know a lot about networking, I've read elsewhere `0.0.0.0` indicates the server will listen for requests from **any** IPv4 address from the internet at large? I am worried this may make my (internet facing) Pi a target for attack, and it seems prudent to limit `ListenAddress` to only listen for requests from my internal network. I won't have need for access anywhere other than home.

My router (Apple Airport) DHCP Range is `10.0.1.2` to `10.0.1.200`, with the router at `10.0.1.1`. (This seems to be the default, if I had known more perhaps I should have changed this to `192.168.1.1`).
I have tried setting the following `ListenAddress` values, all of which have locked me out of SSH, necessitating connecting with a USB serial cable to revert `ListenAddress` back to default:

`10.0.1.0` - I thought setting the last octet at `0` may indicate all IPs on the `10.0.1.` range

`10.0.1.*` - I thought using `*` as a wildcard may work as per the first example as above

`10.0.1.**` - In case the single `*` wildcard only indicated a `.1` to `.9` range

`10.0.1.1` - It seems silly now but I thought setting the router's IP may do the trick, as this is the magic 'box' handing out the IP addresses

`10.0.1.1/24` - Using `/24` to define the first three octets, leaving the last octet as the open 'range'. But it seems `sshd_config` doesn't recognise the `/` character

`127.0.0.1` - I [learned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179325/accepting-ssh-connections-only-from-localhost) [about](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179544/how-do-you-restrict-a-server-to-connections-from-localhost-only) the `localhost` or loop back address option, but this didn't work either

`10.0.1.24` - My computer's IP. This last throw of the dice didn't work, and on running `systemctl status ssh.service` returned `error: Bind to port 22 on 10.0.1.24 failed: Cannot assign requested address`, `fatal: Cannot bind any address` and `Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server` messages.

I hope this goes some way to explaining my thinking, and what I've tried so far - I feel I've exhausted all logical options and perhaps `0.0.0.0` is the only permitted option for what I am trying to achieve. Do let me know if my question is better suited to the networking forum instead.

Worryingly, `systemctl status ssh.service` also advised `Deprecated option` for the following `sshd_config` values:

```
Deprecated option KeyRegenerationInterval
Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Deprecated option KeyRegenerationInterval
Deprecated option RhostsRSAAuthentication
Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
```

However I'm at a loss as to what the program's favoured values for these should be.

I am pushing the limits of my (very limited) knowledge thus far, but I understand from my previous query to this board plenitude and prolixity is encouraged to assist your kind replies.

My `sshd_config` [defaults are v1.103](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/sshd_config)  and the changes I have made are:

```
AddressFamily inet
AllowUsers keith
Protocol 2
LoginGraceTime 30
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
MaxAuthTries 3
MaxSessions 1
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
RSAAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
AuthenticationMethods publickey keyboard-interactive
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding no
PrintMotd no
TCPKeepAlive no
ClientAliveInterval 360
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

I have been using a variety of websites and sources for guidance, so some of these values may now be superannuated. I understand SSH security is constantly evolving and something of a moveable feast.

I hope this explains my thought process and methodology, and my apologies for the lack of brevity. Thank you all for your kind help thus far, it is very much appreciated. Never stop learning!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ListenAddress` is actually telling which system interface the SSH server should listen on (0:0:0:0 makes it listen to all interfaces). For instance if your system has a Wifi (on 10.0.1.4) and an Ethernet (10.0.1.12), `ListenAddress 10.0.1.12` will make it listen only on the Ethernet interface, and other computers will have to SSH to `10.0.1.12` to get a connection.

To restrict external users to a given range of addresses, you can use a firewall, either `iptables` directly (but it isn't fit for mere humans) or a more palatable front-end such as [`ufw`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncomplicated_Firewall).

However, since you are behind a router, the router may already block external accesses, systems on the other side of the router do not see your `10.0.1.*` adress, for them everything comes from a single address: your router, and to initiate connections from outside to one of your local machines the router would have to be set to perform port-forwarding (connections to some specified port on the router are forwarded to a specific local address:port on your local network).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I understand now. I thought `ListenAddress` meant listening for the range of clients trying to connect to the Pi, rather than setting to the IP of the Pi itself. I've set `ListenAddress` to the IP of the Pi and restarted ssh.service, and it hasn't locked me out of SSH, so it is looking good. I have DHCP and NAT enabled at the router and port forwarding isn't enabled, so it must be as you say that the router is blocking external accesses as a first line of defence. I read `iptables` and IP Wrappers are effective so I'll read more into this, thank you.

Comment: If the answer is good, please consider accepting it. Also `ufw` is much easier to use than `iptables` (it is still `iptables` under the hood). There are even GUI front-ends (`gufw`).

Comment: Thank you. I'm still reading up on `iptables` and `ufw` - it is definitely a bit more advanced than my current level but the more I am reading, the more I am understanding! 

Unfortunately I'm no longer able to SSH into my Pi, after setting `ListenAddress` to its IP I am now getting the error `ssh: connect to host [Pi IP] port [#]: Connection refused`. I'll use my serial cable to set `ListenAddress` back to `0.0.0.0` but I'm still at a loss as to what I may be doing wrong? Thank you for your advice and assistance thus far.

Comment: What address are you using? 127.0.0.1?

Comment: For `ListenAddress` I set this to the IP of the Pi, which locked me out of SSH. I used my serial jumper cable to change `ListenAddress` back to `0.0.0.0`, and I can SSH in again now. I tried setting `ListenAddress` to `127.0.0.1` previously, which also locked me out of SSH (I then serial'ed back in to revert to `0.0.0.0` to get SSH access back). I'm using the `10.0.1.*` range - I believe this is an Apple router default unfortunately. If I'd known then what I know now I would have set this to `192.168.*.*`!

Comment: xenoid's suggestion checked as I ultimately used `ufw` as `iptables` looks daunting for a beginner. @LinuxSecurityFreak 's answer was useful as well for setting my `user.rules` so a combination of both replies answered my question, so thank you very much to you both.

Comment: @KeithSavage Always welcome, I recently modified the rule, so I added it too. + Just to note that this site is collecting any and all good questions for future readers, so it's not only about answering you specifically. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

## `iptables` way ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables))

I'd advise to allow local only network to your machine via `iptables`, as I'm doing it this way:

---

### Example such rule taken from my `rules.v4`

#### long version

```
--append INPUT --protocol tcp --match tcp --destination-port 22 --match iprange --src-range 192.168.0.2-192.168.0.254 --match comment --comment "ssh + sshfs" --jump ACCEPT
```

#### short version

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m iprange --src-range 192.168.0.2-192.168.0.254 -m comment --comment "ssh + sshfs" -j ACCEPT
```

---

### Modified example using `conntrack` + specifying `subnet`

#### long version

```
--append INPUT --match conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED --protocol tcp --match tcp --destination-port 22 --source 192.168.0.0/24 --match comment --comment ssh --jump ACCEPT
```

#### short version

```
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 22 -m comment --comment ssh -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep everything in `ssh` by using the "Match" directive in your `sshd_config`

```
# This will disallow everyone
AuthorizedKeysFile /dev/null
# Put the netmask you want to allow here
Match Address 10.0.1.1/24
# Connections from above IP can use normal authorized keys to authenticate
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Best to test from the console to prevent accidentally locking yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I'm still getting the error `ssh: connect to host [Pi Hole IP] port [Pi Hole Port]: Connection refused`. I've set the IP range to my network, so it reads `Match Address 10.0.1.0/24`. The text shows a different colour (green) for `Address`, however is showing the expected colour (red) for the `10.0.1.0/24`, part, however the `/` is showing black. This may be indicating an error of some sort with the use of the forward slash. I don't believe I'll be able to get `Match` to work - I'm unsure if this is because of Debian or my `10.0.1.*` IP range.

Comment: You can troubleshoot by first stopping SSH `sudo service ssh stop` and then running in debug mode with `sudo service ssh start -d`.  This will give you a dump of debug messages to help diagnose the login.  Key things to look for "Connection from xxxx" to verify the IP that SSH is seeing the connections coming from.

I would start out by banning everyone and verifying that works and then with the IP info above try to allow that one IP only (that is, don't use the netmask slash part yet) and see if it works.